# Access text in a textbox by name with a string value

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a WPF noob, having moved from WinForms and I'm trying to access the text in a textbox by name with a string, basically I need the WPF version of Controls.Find() and I can't seem to find anything that works. Here's my code;

```
<TextBox x:Name="amplitude0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Canvas.Left="160" Canvas.Top="64" />
<TextBox x:Name="amplitude1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Canvas.Left="280" Canvas.Top="64" />
```

...up to amplitude9. and the C#;

```
object textBox = new TextBox();

        for (int n = 0; n <= 9; n++)
        {
            txtAmplitude = "amplitude" + n;
            textBox = FindName(txtAmplitude);
            amplitude[n] = textBox.text;
        }
```

I've tried different functions but can't find anything that works, can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your error? What doesn't work? Kind of hard to help without more information.

Comment: the error is in the "amplitude[n] = textBox.text;" line - "object does not contain a definition for text and no extension method text"

Comment: Where is `amplitude[]` defined? And `FindName()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
amplitude[n] = textBox.text;
```

what you want is `amplitude[n] = ((TextBox) textbox).Text;`

This is called casting.

But if you are doing this then you probably is not doing it right. I would suggest you to read more about MVVM design pattern since it is very different from Win form. What you are doing right now can be done easily and cleanly with Binding

Edit:

And `object textBox = new TextBox();` is not needed. you don't need to initialize a new TextBox. Should be something like

```
TextBox textbox;
....
textbox = (TextBox) FindName(....);
```

Comment: That's got it, thanks for your help! I'll have to read into it more, it's been a while since moving to new technology

Comment: I'll add on to this answer, instead of casting, the declaration line should be either  var textbox  = new TextBox()or TextBox textBox = new TextBox(); unless there is some other reason you want the variable to be an object.